# Raycasting in Python (for use in VPython Graphics)

Tags: 3d, raycasting, vpython

I'm working in VPython and would like to know how I use python (and some math) to identify if a ray (line-segment) will intersect a 3D object (mesh).

Here's an image that illustrates my problem: [image: Box with Magenta line going through it and a white line coming off of it]

In this situation, I would like an output that tells me that the magenta line is intersecting the cube (of dots) and the white line is clear.

Thank you in advanced for your help!

This is more specific to VPython, but I would also like to know how I can do this with imported 3D models.

Comment: Alas, this is a tricky geometry question, not really a VPython question. However, it's possible that if you post to the VPython forum someone there might have a suggestion:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users

Comment: Unfortunately, that was what I had done, but I’ve yet to get a response. I had partially moved on by using Unity, but I’m still open to suggestions to doing this via VPython

Comment: That's odd. I tried searching the VPython forum for "ray-casting" or "ray" but didn't find anything.that seemed related.